# Is there are a pivoting trays syntax in spss?

Tags: syntax, pivot-table, spss

I have two variables V1(Categorical), V2 (continuous) and I want to do descriptive statistics on V2 for each category in V1 but I want an output format like second attached image not like the first one, I wrote the following syntax but want to add a command to generate a table like the second image.

```
SORT CASES  BY V1.
SPLIT FILE LAYERED BY V1.
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=V2
 /FORMAT=NOTABLE
 /PERCENTILES=5.0 10.0  
 /STATISTICS=STDDEV VARIANCE RANGE MINIMUM MAXIMUM SEMEAN MEAN MEDIAN MODE SKEWNESS SESKEW 
   KURTOSIS SEKURT
 /ORDER=ANALYSIS.
```

what I get:
[image]

what I want to get:
[image]

Comment: There is no simple syntax to do this :( . For stuff like this you either have to use the Custom Tables module, or do some complex workarounds. For example, in this case, it's possible to capture the results from the output using `OMS` into a new dataset, then use `casestovars` to restructure the data, and after some cleaning up you get a dataset that's the same form as you described. If you want to try this please add some sample data to your post (use the "edit" option) so we can try to write syntax that will do the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get these results (open your original data, without any SPLIT FILE in effect):

```
DATASET COPY  Group1.
DATASET COPY  Group2.
DATASET ACTIVATE  Group1.
FILTER OFF.
USE ALL.
SELECT IF (V1 = 1).
EXECUTE.
DELETE VARIABLES V1.
RENAME VARIABLES (V2=Category_1).

DATASET ACTIVATE  Group2.
FILTER OFF.
USE ALL.
SELECT IF (V1 = 2).
EXECUTE.
DELETE VARIABLES V1.
RENAME VARIABLES (V2=Category_2).
MATCH FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='Group1'.
EXECUTE.

FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=Category_1 Category_2
 /FORMAT=NOTABLE
 /PERCENTILES=5.0 10.0  
 /STATISTICS=STDDEV VARIANCE RANGE MINIMUM MAXIMUM SEMEAN MEAN MEDIAN MODE SKEWNESS SESKEW KURTOSIS SEKURT.
```

If you have more than two values for V1, you'd need to add additional commands to create data sets with additional category variables.